# Dynamic programming- Longest common substring explanation

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I am a newbie trying to wrap my head around Dynamic programming and this seems like an enigma to me. I was looking at the Longest common substring problem's solution using DP. Its code below:-

```
int dp[N+1][N+1];

for (int i = 0; i <= N; ++i)

  dp[0][i] = dp[i][0] = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)

  for (int j = 1; j <= N; ++j) {

    dp[i][j] = max(dp[i-1][j], dp[i][j-1]);

    if (A[i-1] == B[j-1])

      dp[i][j] = max(dp[i][j], dp[i-1][j-1]+1);

  }


int answer = dp[N][N];
```

Its solution looks pretty simple but I am having a difficult time understanding the solution. Can someone please explain what is happening in the code and how does this solve the LCS problem?

Comment: Have a look at this first: https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/dynamic-programming-from-novice-to-advanced/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to understand the general idea of the solution. 
Here are a few references, from the simplest explanations to the more deep ones:

1. Wiki - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem
2. YouTube - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSwu8Z9nzOg

and for the academic references regarding this solution you are presenting above:

3. MIT - http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-15-dynamic-programming-longest-common-subsequence/lec15.pdf
4. Corenell - http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~wdtseng/icpc/notes/dp2.pdf
5. CMU - http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15451-f10/www/lectures/lect0928.pdf

Then, after understanding their solution and their way of solving this problem, you'll see that you may implement it by yourself or fully understand the logic in your algorithm

good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable links.